# OSGi 'immediate = true' component not activated

Tags: java, osgi

I'm trying to run the following code

```
@Component(name = "compname", immediate = true)
public class DemoComponent {

    private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(DemoComponent.class);

    @Activate
    protected void activate(ComponentContext context) {

        try {
            //my code
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //catch
        }

        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug("Demo component is activated ");
        }
    }
}
```

When the application is started the activate method is not called. I've tried setting a debug pointer inside the try block. There are other components in the same project that gets activated.

Comment: In what environment do you install the bundle?

Comment: You need to provide more info in order to reproduce the scenario and help you better: environment, versions, etc. Otherwise it is hard to give you an accurate answer.

Comment: Any errors in some log file you can share with us? Furthermore, you should not set `name` in `@Component` like this. Usually, this is meant to be the FQDN of the class (package + class name). Setting the name usually leads to side effects. Since you do not implement an interface I would also suggest to set `service = DemoComponent.class` in the `@Component` annotation. The missing `service` property might already be the issue.